# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in vuejs jest typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, jestjs, babeljs

I am having this problem in my Jest test case using my VueJs  + Jest + Typescript

when I run

**vue-cli-service test:unit**

I am getting the following error trans-piling my ts tests and test fail with below error.

**SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

```
  30 |   inject
  31 | } from "@vue/composition-api";
> 32 | import { stopWatchingProperties } from "@mymods/modui-framework";
     | ^
  33 | import { reactive } from "@vue/composition-api";
  34 | 
  35 | export default {

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at src/App.vue:32:1
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.vue:66:3)
```

My **jest.config**

```
moduleFileExtensions: [
        "js",
        "jsx",
        "json",
        "vue",
        "ts",
        "tsx"
    ],
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
        "/node_modules/"
    ],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
    ],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
        ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub",
        "^.+\\.(tsx|ts)?$": "ts-jest"
       //"^.+\\.tsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
```

My **babel.config**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
};
```

**Package.json**

```
dependencies": {
    "@mymods/modui-framework": "0.0.6",
```

Any ideas, modui-framework is my dependency and is loaded in node-modules from a different project and that in turn depends on another project.

Any suggestions/ideas ?

Comment: please  share the test file

Comment: normally this is solved by adding something like `'/node_modules/(?!@mymods/modui-framework).+\\.js$',` to your `transformIgnorePatterns`